# Sine definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anyone explain why this is true and how to reach this conclusion?

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin^{(2l+1)}\theta \ \ d\theta  = 2\frac{(2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(2l))}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot(2l+1)} $$

being $l$ an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$I_l=\int_0^\pi\sin^{2l+1}\theta d\theta$$
Then
$$I_l=\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2l}\theta d(-\cos\theta)$$
$$=-\cos\theta\sin^{2l}\theta\bigg|_0^{\pi}-\int_0^{\pi}-\cos\theta d(\sin^{2l}\theta)$$
$$\int_0^{\pi}\cos\theta(2l)\sin^{2l-1}\theta\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$=2l\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2l-1}\theta\cos^2\theta d\theta$$
$$=2l\int_0^{\pi}\sin^{2l-1}\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)d\theta$$
$$=2l\left(I_{l-1}-I_l\right)$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: yea i think so. Basically we have a recursion formula so if we get the first term of the sequence ( $ I_{0} $ for $ l=1$ ) which is 2 we can get the next term and so on using  : $ I_{l}= \frac{2l}{2l+1}\ I_{l-1}$ which for any $ l$ gives the expression we're looking for. Thanks for the help!